# CCArray enumerator object

Tags: arrays, iterator, cocos2d-x, enumerator

As far as I know it doesn't exist.

```
    CCArray *array = CCArray::create();
    CCArrayEnumerator *enumerator = array->createEnumerator();
    ...

    CCObject *nextObjectOrNull = enumerator->nextObject();
    CCObject *currentObjectOrNull = enumerator->peekCurrentObject();
```

This class would make my code simpler, and if no one coded it, I will do it no time. But I haven't found any requests or forum posts about the need for this class. Which is strange.

Comment: ... and your question being?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple class, which does the job. Suggestions are welcome.

CCArrayEnumerator.h:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

class CCArrayEnumerator : public cocos2d::CCObject{

public:
    static CCArrayEnumerator* create(cocos2d::CCArray* array);
    cocos2d::CCObject* nextObject();
    cocos2d::CCObject* peekCurrentObject();
private:
    cocos2d::CCArray* _array;
    CCArrayEnumerator();
    ~CCArrayEnumerator();
    virtual bool init(cocos2d::CCArray* array);

    int _currentIndex;
};
```

CCArrayEnumerator.cpp:

```
#include "CCArrayEnumerator.h"
USING_NS_CC;

CCArrayEnumerator* CCArrayEnumerator::create(cocos2d::CCArray* array){
    CCArrayEnumerator *pRet = new CCArrayEnumerator();
    if (pRet && pRet->init(array))
    {
        pRet->autorelease();
        return pRet;
    }
    else
    {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(pRet);
        return NULL;
    }
}

    cocos2d::CCObject* CCArrayEnumerator::nextObject(){
    CCObject *retval = NULL;

    if(_array->count() > _currentIndex + 1){
        _currentIndex++;
        retval = _array->objectAtIndex(_currentIndex);
    }

    return retval;
}

cocos2d::CCObject* CCArrayEnumerator::peekCurrentObject(){
    CCObject *retval = NULL;

    if(_currentIndex != -1 && _array->count() > _currentIndex){
        retval = _array->objectAtIndex(_currentIndex);
    }

    return retval;
}

CCArrayEnumerator::CCArrayEnumerator():
 _array(NULL)
,_currentIndex(-1){

}

CCArrayEnumerator::~CCArrayEnumerator(){
    if(_array){
        _array->release();
        _array = NULL;
    }
}

bool CCArrayEnumerator::init(cocos2d::CCArray* array){

    // Superclass CCObject has no init.

    CCAssert(_array == NULL,"CCArrayEnumerator is already initialized.");

    _array = array;
    _array->retain();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own code but there is already a macro which can be used for same.

Here is pseudo code:

```
CCArray *array = this->getChildren();  

CCObject* currentObject = NULL;  
CCARRAY_FOREACH(array , currentObject )  
{  
    CCNode *node = (CCNode*)currentObject;
}
```